# Converting a labeled factor to original data

Tags: r

If `numeric` data convert to `factor` with manipulated levels or labels like :

```r
original <- c(1.1,2.1,2.1,1.1,2.1)
manipulated <- factor(original, labels = c("one", "two") )
```

Is there any way to convert `manipulated` to `original` ? if not, is not better it was reversable?

Comment: I think, the question was discussed here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to reverse that change.  If you did

```
original <- c(1.1,2.1,2.1,1.1,2.1)
manipulated <- factor(original)
```

then the values 1.1 and 2.1 would be converted to character strings and stored as the levels.  But your conversion

```
manipulated <- factor(original, labels = c("one", "two") )
```

overwrites the levels with `c("one", "two")`, so the original values are no longer part of `manipulated`.

If you wanted the change to be reversible, you could do the manipulation in two steps:

```r
original <- c(1.1,2.1,2.1,1.1,2.1)
manipulated <- factor(original)
savedLevels <- levels(manipulated)
levels(manipulated) <- c("one", "two")

restored <- as.numeric( savedLevels[manipulated] )
restored
#> [1] 1.1 2.1 2.1 1.1 2.1
```

It's not guaranteed to be perfect since character versions of numbers aren't exact, but it's going to be very close.